# Queries and Mutation not getting update at /graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I have created multiple queries and mutations using apollo server. But they are not getting updated at http://localhost:8081/graphql.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. One of the things we will need you to do is provide more specific information about your set up. Apollo Server v4 is the latest version and will set up your server at port 4000 by default. Try navigating to `localhost:4000/graphql` instead. If that doesn't work, you can find the "Getting Started" documentation [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/).
If you have other specific information about your setup that differs from the documentation on that page, please update the question and I can circle back on this.

Hope that helps and happy coding :)